# Custom WordPress URL Structure

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to ensure the WordPress site I'm working on maintains consistent URLs. The problem I'm having is with child pages and custom post types.

Essentially the setup is as follows.

/main-page/sub-page/

```
Main Page
-- Child Page
```

This is fine, however I have a custom post type (research-papers) I'd like to list on the Child Page. I've got this working fine. The problem I'm having is getting the research papers post type to use the following URL structure:

```
/main-page/sub-page/research-paper-title/
```

I've looked at wp_rewrite_rule but I can't get anything working. Any ideas?

```
add_rewrite_rule(  
    "main-page/sub-page/([^/]+)/?",  
    "index.php?research-paper=$matches[1]",  
    "top"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first parameter from
`"main-page/sub-page/([^/]+)/?"`
to 
`"main-page/sub-page/([.]+)/?"`

The way it's set up now, you are searching for the pattern "main-page/sub-page//...", with 2 forward slashes after "sub-page", which isn't going to catch anything.